Swagger - Values displayed in the response body are rounded int values for long(int64) datatype
I'm using long data type for one of the field for which it shows as int(64) on swagger. I noticed one issue with the response of one of the API on swagger that it's converting/rounding the value of this field when you have high number.
For eg: Any value greater than 9223372036000000000 is shown as 9223372036000000000 in the response body of swagger. But when I run the same API from postman it shows correct values.
Really appreciate if some one could help on fixing this issue.
Here is the sample code:
     // Domain
        @Schema
        public class Payments {
            @Schema(description = "Unique identifier")
            private int id;
            @Schema(description = "Unique identifier of the check")
            private Long checkId;
        
           // setters and getters
        
        }
        
        // Controller
        @RestController
        @Tag(name = "payments")
        public class PaymentsController {
                @Autowired
                private PaymentService paymentService;
        
            @Operation(description = "test description")
            @GetMapping(value = "/v1/payments", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            public ResponseEntity<Payment> getPaymentDetails(
                    @RequestParam(value = "siteId", required = true) Long siteId, HttpServletRequest request)
                    throws ParseException, JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
                List<Payment> response = paymentService.getPayments(siteId, request);
                
                return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);
            }
        
        }
        
        // Service
        @Service
        public class PaymentService {
            @Autowired
            private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
            @Transactional
            public List<Payment> getPayments(Long siteId, HttpServletRequest request) throws ParseException, JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
            
            Session sessionObj = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Query query = null;
            String paymentsQuery = "select id, check_id from payments where site_id = :siteId";
            query = sessionObj.createNativeQuery(paymentsQuery);
            query.setParameter("siteId", siteId);
            List<Object[]> resultList = query.getResultList();
            List<Payment> list = constructPaymentsDTOObject(resultList);
            return list;
        
           }
           private List<Object> constructPaymentsDTOObject(List<Object[]> resultList) throws ParseException {
            List<Payment> list = new ArrayList<Payment>();
            if (resultList.size() > 0) {
                for (Object[] results : resultList) {
                    Payment paymentsDTO = new Payment();
                    paymentsDTO.setId(Integer.parseInt(results[0].toString()));
                    paymentsDTO.setCheckId(Long.parseLong(results[1].toString()));
                    list.add(paymentsDTO);
                }
            }
            
            return list;
           }
        }
    
    DB:
    +--------+--------------------------+
| id          | check_id |
+--------+--------------------------+
| 105210392   | 9223372036000000000 |
| 105210398   | 9223372036000000005 |
| 105210400   | 9223372036000000006 |
+--------+---------------------------

In this case all checkid's showing same value as '9223372036000000000'.
Please check this screenshot.

We can use String instead of Long, but we need to use Long for this use case.

Could you please add the code snippets for a better analysis of this issue?

@SharadNanda Added code snippet and screenshot of swagger response, please let me know if you need any additional info.
